# Vagrant - local host connection refused

Tags: python, webserver, vagrant

I am trying to set up a simple hello world. I'm running a server using python and have my vagrant file to foward localhost:8080 to vagrant server 8080 which outputs a simple HTML hello message. When I type in Localhost:8080 on my local machine however the connection is refused. Here is the vagrant file and my python web server code.

Vagrant File:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "pg_config.sh"
  # config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080, autocorrect: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5000
end
```

Webserver.py

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class WebServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
            if self.path.endswith("/hello"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()

                output = ""
                output += "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
                self.wfile.write(output)
                print output
                return
            else:
                self.send_error(404, "File Not Found %s" % self.path)


def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('',port), WebServerHandler)
        print "Web Server is now running on port %s" % port
        server.serve_forever()   #constantly runs unless keyboard interrupted

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "^c entered, stopping web server..."
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` on the vagrant guest host.Then try to access it instead of the script.This way you can make sure it is not a network error from virtualbox

Comment: Can you browse to it using any ol' web browser? Also did you check if you have any firewall running on the system?

Comment: I did #1 and still couldn't access it via localhost:8000. So assuming its a network issue what do i do? FYI. No firewalls up.

Comment: I also tried to run the webserver.py on just my local terminal and I still couldn't connect to localhost:8080

Comment: I solved the problem. I needed to type in http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello instead of localhost:8080/hello